# How can I deleted repetitive values in my hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash, delete-row

I have a text file with 300 rows and 100 of this rows are repeated. I dont know how search in my hash and delete this repetitions.

This is my perl code when I must add the new code lines:

[image]

Comment: Please don't include code as image - include it as text with proper code formatting (read the available help if unclear how to do this). Also, this is no code writing service but it looks like that you did not even made the slightest attempt to solve the relevant part of the problem yourself. Please first try yourself or at least explain how do you think it might be done or where exactly your problems are. My current guess is that you are not familiar with what a hash is in the first place since once the concept behind a hash is known the solution should be straight forward.

Comment: Example input and expected output is missing too.

Comment: Use a HoH instead of a HoA to get rid of the duplicates. You can always convert it to an HoA later.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `uniq()` from `List::MoreUtils` module to have a single item in an array, and its better to remove duplicated items before making them keys in your hash

something like This will do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my %cathmin;

open (LIST, "<cath_min.txt") || die "[-] Can't open the file";
my @list = <LIST>; # load your array from your file
close LIST;

@list = uniq(@list); # remove duplicated items in array

foreach my $item (@list) {
  chomp $item;
  # here you can do what you want
}

print Dumper(\%cathmin); # check your hash contents
```

Comment: You shouldn't use global filehandles. (`open my $fp_list` is much better than `open LIST`).